# Prevent JavaScript from breaking with a 403 HTTP response

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-403

I'm grabbing user information from the Last.fm website with a JQuery $.get request.

Since some users' accounts are private, I sometimes receive a 403 error stating that authentication is required. This breaks the JS code. The last.fm API doesn't let you see if a user is private or not.

Is there a way to catch this error and continue through the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works with cross-domain requests, but you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  statusCode: {
    403: function() {
      alert('a 403 was received');
    }
  },
  success: function() {
     alert('everything OK');
  }
});
```

Or possibly set it up in $.ajaxSetup() if it works ?

Comment: I've actually tried this and it will recognize when there's an error, but I want it to just swallow up the problem and move on. Is there a way to say "ignore it!" when it finds the error?

Comment: Well, sure it is, but if there's an error the authentication info isn't retrived, so it would depend on the rest of your script, the Ajax function itself won't break your JS, something else will, so you will have to do some checks to see if the info you have matches what is expected, and if it does not do something appropriate for that info etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using a proxy to get the data from API since $.ajax()  error handler won;t return errors for cross domain requests per jQery API docs:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

EDIT Note in docs for error option:

"Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests."